# django decode url error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When passing timestamp as filter parameters, I got UnicodeDecodeError:

- My request:

  > curl  "http://localhost:8000/events?from=1985­-10­-26T09:00:00Z&to=1985­-10­27T09:00:00Z"
- Error:

  > File ".env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 153, in get_environ
  >   if '?' in path:
  >   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
- Two parameters I got from GET "from" and "to" have weird characters:

  > 1985\xc2\xad10\xc2\xad26T09:00:00Z

I tried to decode it using "UTF-8" but did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, when triyng to add some Unicode string to GET-parameter (for example, `/search?city=Москва`). Is there some updates? I've read all browser's show perform "percent-encoding" for each URL before sending actual request, but it seems like IE8 does not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a `django` related problem. You have to encode special characters in urls. With `curl` you can do that adding `--data-urlencode`

So your request should look like this:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/events --data-urlencode from=1985­-10­-26T09:00:00Z to=1985­-10­27T09:00:00Z
```

Comment: This will post data (not GET). btw, the error also happened if I enter that url in browser (which is encoded by browser before sending to server)